# Mongodb : resquest between two collections

Tags: mongodb, collections, find

Here is the problem I'm struggling with :

I have two collections in mongodb :

One User and one Contract which contains a field conUser that references a User.

I would like to find all the users that don't have any contract.

How can I query that ?

Thank you very much :)

Here is a sample of my Users :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5981aae07f6e1da1030041a7"),
    "usrCreatedAt" : "2017-08-02 12:35:12",
    "usrMail" : "lkjlh@cncnn.com",
    "usrFirstname" : "ezaeddd",
    "usrLastname" : "aze",
    "usrDocStatus" : "creating"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58d3ec3c7f6e1d93060041a8"),
    "usrMail" : "aaaa.bbbb@gmail.com",
    "usrFirstname" : "AAAAA",
    "usrLastname" : "BBBBB",
    "usrDocStatus" : "creating"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56eae6b87f6e1d25130041a8"),
    "usrMail" : "barbara_bhdgxat_bushaksky@tfbnw.net",
    "usrFirstname" : "Barbara",
    "usrLastname" : "Bushaksky",
    "usrDocStatus" : "creating"
}
```

And some Contracts :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58d3ec3f7f6e1d93060041a9"),
    "conDocStatus" : "creating",
    "conBeginAt" : "2017-03-16",
    "conEndAt" : "2019-04-10",
    "conUser" : {
        "$ref" : "User",
        "$id" : ObjectId("58d3ec3c7f6e1d93060041a8"),
        "$db" : "angios"
    },
    "conUpdatedAt" : "2017-08-01 14:10:07"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56aef7ca3ce0417db7d761da"),
    "conDocStatus" : "creating",
    "conBeginAt" : "2016-02-12",
    "conUser" : {
        "$ref" : "User",
        "$id" : ObjectId("56eae6b87f6e1d25130041a8"),
        "$db" : "angios"
    }
}
```

The request should return :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5981aae07f6e1da1030041a7"),
    "usrCreatedAt" : "2017-08-02 12:35:12",
    "usrMail" : "lkjlh@cncnn.com",
    "usrFirstname" : "ezaeddd",
    "usrLastname" : "aze",
    "usrDocStatus" : "creating"
}
```

Comment: You can use $exists query operator to search documents which don’t have contract field. Link to MongoDB docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Comment: Can you paste sample data from your both collections here?

Comment: I edited my question to add some data.